# any way to increase speed every time it hits paddle in brick breaker game with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a brick breaker game and I want to increase speed every time it hits the paddle. But when I add 1 in the speed for some reason it increases multiple times.
here's my code

```
 if ball.colliderect(paddle):
        y_positive = False
        y_negative = True
        ball_speed += 1
```

Comment: It increase "multiple times"... What do you mean by that exactly ? Does it accelerate more than you anticipated ? If that's the case, my guess is that it's because the collision is detected multiple times. When you're resolving a collision, you also need to update the ball's position, not just redirect it's velocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's happening *every clocktick that their collisionbox overlaps.*  They might be touching for a few frames before they are far enough apart to no longer be considered colliding.  You need to put in logic to allow only one increment per volley.

```
volley = False  ##  only allow increment once ball crosses midpoint of screen
if ball.x > screen_width /2: volley = True

if ball.colliderect( paddle ) and volley:
    y_positive = False
    y_negative = True
    ball_speed += 1
    volley = False
```

---

Alternatively, once the ball touches, nudge it far enough away from paddle to ensure that their collisionboxes don't touch.

```
if ball.colliderect( paddle ):
    y_positive = False
    y_negative = True
    ball_speed += 1
    ball.x += ball.width /2
```

Nudge it however far it needs.